# react.js trigger event inside another component upon button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building my first web app with react. Its a chat with multiple chat rooms. This is what I got visually:

[image]

Now I simply want to click on "open" on any room and display the messages within that chatroom inside the white div on the right currently saying "HI MOM".

But these two are different components.

This is the list of chatrooms:

```
export default function ChatRoomList({param1}) {
    const [chatRooms, setChatRooms] = React.useState([]);
    React.useEffect(()=>{
      (async () => {
          var x = await getChatRoom(param1)
          console.log(x)
          setChatRooms(x)
      })()
    },[])  
  
      return  (
          <div className='chatRoomView'>
               {chatRooms.map((chatRoom , index) => {
                  return (
                      <ul >
                        <li key={index}>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        ChatroomID: {chatRoom.chatIDFromTableChats}
                                        <br></br>
                                        Username:  {chatRoom.userNameUser2}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => loadChatRoomFromID(chatRoom.chatIDFromTableChats)}>open</Button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                      </ul>                   
                  )             
               })}
          </div>
      );
    }
  
    function loadChatRoomFromID(ID) {
       alert(`chatRoomID: ${ID}`);
    }
```

Upon button click I am currently just able to open an alert displaying the ID of the clicked element.

Here is component two:

```
export default function ChatMessages() {

function loadMessages(ID){
    // HELP NEEDED?!
}

    return  <div class='mainChatView'>HI MOM</div>;
      
}
```

As you can see, there is a function called "loadMessages()" but it doesnt do anything since it needs to get the ID param passed and then start loading the messages of each room.

The connection from one to the other component is missing and so far, no answer i read about didnt fail miserably for me...

Can someone give me a working code example and explain what is happening?

Thank you!

Comment: you can use something like context api or redux

Comment: You deleted the question so I'm commenting here: how to lift up state: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-breeze-gg4l6?file=/src/App.js (you had broken code in multiple places)

Comment: thank you very much, while typing out the question I realized my mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, data can only be passed down from parent to child via props (see note at the end for more detail on this), not from sibling to sibling. This doesn't mean, however, that siblings cannot cause updates in each other, it just means that you need to restructure your code a bit so that data flows down properly.

You can store the active chatroom ID in the parent of the list and detail views and let the list view update the ID while the detail view uses the ID to load messages.

Here's a simple example:

```
function Chat() {
    const [activeRoomID, setActiveRoomID] = React.useState(null);

    const onActiveChange = React.useCallback((id) => {
        setActiveRoomID(id);
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <div>
            <ChatRoomList onActiveChange={onActiveChange}/>
            <ChatMessages id={activeRoomID}/>
        </div>
    )
}

function ChatRoomList({ onActiveChange }) {
    // ...

    return (
        <div>
            {chatRooms.map(chatRoom => (
                <div key={chatRoom.chatIDFromTableChats}>
                    <div>ChatroomID: {chatRoom.chatIDFromTableChats}</div>
                    <Button onClick={() => onActiveChange(chatRoom.chatIDFromTableChats)}>Open</Button>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

function ChatMessages({ id }) {
    // load messages for `id` and display
}
```

Notice that the data only flows down from the `<Chat>` component to its children.

Note about data only flowing from parent to child: There are additional complexities to this statement. As this example shows, children can also pass data up to their parents but only by using a callback function provided via props, so the React-specific parts still only allow data to flow down. Also the context API allows for passing data to deep descendants (not just children).

Comment: Hello and thank you. My problem is however, that both of those components are loaded from another parent, so I never load ChatRoomList from inside Chat... Is this an issue?

Comment: @innom the `activeRoomID` doesn't need to be held by the parent per se, just by some component above, even if it's a few levels up. This `Chat` component was meant to be a generic parent/ancestor component. Just pass the props down through components along the way. If it's many levels up you might consider using the context API, which I can include in this answer if you're interested